# How to get SelectStatement from Procedure?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-data-tools, dac, scriptdom

This is a follow up question from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29542825/using-ssdt-as-source-for-t4-templates/29567762). I'm trying to use [DACExtensions](https://github.com/Microsoft/DACExtensions) to retrieve the `SelectStatement` objects from a `Procedure` so that I can generate wrapper functions from my SSDT project using a T4 template. The problem is that the Nodes property of my Visitor object doesn't have any nodes in it. What am I missing?

Here's my Visitor:

```
public class SelectVisitor : TSqlFragmentVisitor
{
    public SelectVisitor() { this.Nodes = new List<SelectStatement>(); }
    public List<SelectStatement> Nodes { get; private set; }
    public override void Visit(SelectStatement node)
    {
        base.Visit(node);
        this.Nodes.Add(node);
    }
}
```

And here is how I'm trying to use it:

```
// Create the model
var procFiles = Directory.GetFiles(sqlPath, "*.sql", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
var model = new TSqlTypedModel(SqlServerVersion.Sql100, new TSqlModelOptions());
foreach(var procFile in procFiles)
{
    model.AddObjects(File.ReadAllText(procFile));
}

// Loop through the procs
var procs = model.GetObjects<TSqlProcedure>(DacQueryScopes.UserDefined);
foreach(var proc in procs){ 
    var selectVisitor = new SelectVisitor();
    var ast = proc.GetAst();
    ast.Accept(selectVisitor);
    foreach(var node in selectVisitor.Nodes){
        // Nodes has Count=0 :(
    }
}
```

Comment: Even though it says [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dac.model.tsqlmodel.isscriptbacked.aspx#P:Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.Model.TSqlModel.IsScriptBacked) that empty models are script-backed by default, I thought I'd try creating a dacpac from the model with `loadAsScriptBackedModel` set to true as seen [here](https://github.com/GoEddie/DacpacExplorer/commit/be821f2505aab4e5a6c2510db0cb505323bfe534), but that also did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [TSqlModelUtils.TryGetFragmentForAnalysis](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dac.tsqlmodelutils.trygetfragmentforanalysis.aspx#M:Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.TSqlModelUtils.TryGetFragmentForAnalysis(Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.Model.TSqlObject,Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom.TSqlFragment@)) should ensure you get the original AST inside the model - hopefully that will have what you need. You may want to debug in and view your AST and what actually gets created - that's how we do things internally and often you may be surprised about what actually gets generated. Finally note that the [DacpacExplorer](https://github.com/GoEddie/DacpacExplorer) tool might make this easier to visualize - it should now have support for showing the AST behind an object such as a procedure.

Comment: Ah, thank you so much. That is exactly what I needed to get those darn SelectStatement's. This is going to be a very cool framework when I'm done with it. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks again Kevin. Here's my first release if you're curious: https://github.com/aeslinger0/sqlsharpener

Comment: Brilliant! I'll check this out for sure, great work. And thanks for using MIT license, that makes it easier for me to be allowed to view the code :-)

Comment: No problem! It's still a little rough, but it has only been a week. :) I have some more things I want to add yet - including your idea for EF code-first entities.